# Javascript to highlight today's date in an APEX Report

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible to create a Javascript function that will highlight a Today's Date cell on a Report I am running on an Oracle APEX report?

This report is used to monitor people's availability, so having today's date highlighted on page-load would be very useful for end-users.

An extra bonus would be for the page to load with that cell at the top of the report or auto-scroll the page down to it, but that's future speculations!

Since there isn't much under APEX on this website, I was stuck where to begin, but I hope that this is any help at all...

Comment: what does the generated html look like

Comment: @PatrickEvans I should have added this earlier, my apologies, the Report is in SQL.

Comment: but the reports are shown on a webpage, as you mention page-load, correct?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes that is correct. I don't understand what you're asking for

Comment: if the reports are shown on a webpage they are displayed using html, in order to highlight Today's Date, we need to know what the html that is being used to display that looks like(the html code). You can "View Page Source" or use the browsers developer console (usually hitting F12 will show it), or look at the apex template files it should be in there.

Comment: @PatrickEvans so the source code?

Comment: yes the html source code

Comment: What version of Apex are you using? To clarify, are you using Classic Report? or Interactive?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I can't send that over here, since it has company information on.

Comment: @IanCarpenter I am using Application Express 4.2.2.00.11
And I am using a Classic Report, I believe

Comment: Remove the company data and put in fake data, again only need  part of the HTML source, the part that makes up what you want highlighted

Comment: @PatrickEvans sorry for the delay... Please download the screenshots of that section here: https://robovisits.com/images/apex_dates.zip

Comment: Are the column headers the actual dates of the days in the current month? You can scroll through the months? Is there a page item or something which holds the current month/year? Can you share some screenshots of the report template?

Answer (score 0):

Using a classic report, simply go the column attributes and use the `Highlight Words` property under 
`Column Formatting` attributes.

You can enter static text or reference application/page items.

In your case you can create an application item (let's say `CURRENT_DATE`) that will hold the today's date in a format that match the one displayed in your report. And then simply use this reference by entering `&CURRENT_DATE.` in the `Highlight Words` field.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm not the best user of APEX... I'm struggling to create the Page Item, can you elaborate, please?

Comment: If you use the current date in the page only, indeed you can go with a page item instead of an application item. First create an item (hidden) on your page, then create a page computation (Before header) of type _PL/SQL function Body_ and use the following code : `return to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD');`. Adjust the date format to match the one used in your report. Finally reference this item in the _Highlight Words_ field in the report attributes.